# Get absolute position of character in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jeditorpane, baseline

[image: 1]

I need the absolute position of the charater. With:
`editorPane.getFontMetrics(f).getAscent()`

I only get a relative distance to the baseline. Maybe there is a way to get the absolute position of the baseline?

EDIT:
This is the result of [rect.y + rect.height - metrics.getDescent() - metrics.getAscent()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEkP6.jpg)

Comment: Call the JEditorPane’s [modelToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#modelToView-int-) method.

Comment: ModelToView does not work. It returns 0 for the y value. The height is like the word "World". I need y-coordinate of the beginning of the word "Hello".

Comment: You will need to compute it from the bottom of the view rectangle:  `rect.y + rect.height - metrics.getDescent() - metrics.getAscent()` (where `rect` is the value returned by modelToView)

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. Ascent + descent + leading = height. It is the height of the Highlighter. So I missed the space under the Highlighter.

Comment: How are you obtaining the Font which you use to obtain a FontMetrics?

Comment: Font font = new Font((String) set.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontFamily), Font.BOLD, (Integer) set.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize));

Comment: And the set: AttributeSet set = ((AttributeSet)((StyledDocument)editorPane.getDocument()).getCharacterElement(pos));

Comment: Have you verified that the font is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yeah, It is the current font.

Comment: Is it the smaller font, or the larger font?

Comment: The problem is the smaller font

Answer (score 1):

Since all fonts in a line share a baseline<sup>*</sup>, you can compute a character’s visual position by calling [modelToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#modelToView-int-) and subtracting the descent and ascent from the bottom of the rectangle.

Since multiple fonts are involved, obviously the getFont method of JEditorPane is not sufficient.  The document’s raw element attributes are also insufficient, as an HTMLDocument’s attributes merely model the HTML elements themselves.  However, the actual font for any document position can be obtained from the corresponding [View](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/View.html):

```
static Point getLocation(int pos,
                         JEditorPane editorPane)
throws BadLocationException {

    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) editorPane.getDocument();

    View view = editorPane.getUI().getRootView(editorPane);
    int index;
    while ((index = view.getViewIndex(pos, Position.Bias.Backward)) >= 0) {
        view = view.getView(index);
    }

    AttributeSet attr = doc.getStyleSheet().getViewAttributes(view);
    Font f = doc.getStyleSheet().getFont(attr);

    FontMetrics metrics = editorPane.getFontMetrics(f);
    Rectangle rect = editorPane.modelToView(pos);

    return new Point(rect.x,
        rect.y + rect.height - metrics.getDescent() - metrics.getAscent());
}
```

<sup>* For simplicity, I’m ignoring characters with hanging baselines and vertical baselines.</sup>

**Edit:** Since the RTFEditorKit is rarely used, I incorrectly assumed you were using an HTMLEditorKit.  This will work with RTF documents:

```
static Point getLocation(int pos,
                     JEditorPane editorPane)
throws BadLocationException {
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) editorPane.getDocument();
    View view = editorPane.getUI().getRootView(editorPane);
    int index;
    while ((index = view.getViewIndex(pos, Position.Bias.Backward)) >= 0) {
        view = view.getView(index);
    }

    AttributeSet attr = view.getAttributes();
    Font f = doc.getFont(attr);

    FontMetrics metrics = editorPane.getFontMetrics(f);
    Rectangle rect = editorPane.modelToView(pos);

    return new Point(rect.x,
        rect.y + rect.height - metrics.getDescent() - metrics.getAscent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the RTFEditorKit. So I changed the code:

```
static Point getLocation(int pos,
            JEditorPane editorPane)
            throws BadLocationException {

        View view = editorPane.getUI().getRootView(editorPane);
        int index;
        while ((index = view.getViewIndex(pos, Position.Bias.Backward)) >= 0) {
            view = view.getView(index);
        }

        AttributeSet set = view.getAttributes();
        if (set != null && set.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontFamily) != null) {
            Font f = new Font((String) set.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontFamily), Font.PLAIN, (Integer) set.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize));
            FontMetrics metrics = editorPane.getFontMetrics(f);

            Rectangle rect = editorPane.modelToView(pos);
            return new Point(rect.x,
                    rect.y + rect.height - metrics.getDescent() - metrics.getAscent());
        }
        else {
            return new Point(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

But I always get the ascent of the current Font and not the ascent of the largest Font.

Comment: Isn’t that what you want?  Are you saying you always wanted the ascent of the largest font on the line, rather than the ascent of the font at the desired position?

Comment: Yeah, I need the ascent of the largest font. But I always get the ascent of the current position.

Comment: This seems to conflict with the image in your question, which has a red arrow pointing to the top of the smaller font.  Also, you commented: “ModelToView does not work. It returns 0 for the y value. The height is like the word "World". I need y-coordinate of the beginning of the word "Hello".” So, do you want the y-coordinate for text in the larger font, or the y-coordinate of text in the smaller font?

Comment: I want to set the caret to the right position (the arrow). The y-coordinate is r.y + (ascent of largest font - ascent of current font).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a text cursor which is as tall as the tallest font on the line, regardless of the font size at the cursor’s position.  Correct?

Comment: No, I want a text cursor that has the size of the font size at the cursor’s position.

Comment: Then why do you want the ascent of the largest font?

Comment: y = (r.y +(ascent of largest font - ascent of current font)) or not?

Comment: That might work.  But it seems to me calculating the result using just the font at the desired position would be more reliable.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with RTF documents.